# Bidirectional Communication Between Directives and Controllers in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to communication between directive and controller. so write this sample code but it not work!what is my problem? 
do have another way for this issue?

```js
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.directiveButtonClicked = function () {
            // Controller reacting to call initiated by directive
            alert('Button was clicked in directive');
            console.log("dfg dfg dfg dfg");
        }
    }); 

    myApp.directive("myDirective",function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<button ng-click="buttonClicked">Click Me</button>',
            scope: {
                onButtonClick: '&'
            },
            link: link
        };

        function link(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.buttonClicked = function () {
            // Button was clicked in the directive
            // Invoke callback function on the controller
            scope.onButtonClick();
        }
     }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
       <my-directive on-button-click="vm.directiveButtonClicked" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93sufr7L/14/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `()` to functions in both `on-button-click` and `ng-click`:

```js
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.directiveButtonClicked = function () {
            // Controller reacting to call initiated by directive
            alert('Button was clicked in directive');
            console.log("dfg dfg dfg dfg");
        };
    }); 

    myApp.directive("myDirective",function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<button ng-click="buttonClicked()">Click Me</button>',
            scope: {
                onButtonClick: '&'
            },
            link: link
        };

        function link(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            scope.buttonClicked = function () {
                // Button was clicked in the directive
                // Invoke callback function on the controller
                scope.onButtonClick();
            };
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
       <my-directive on-button-click="vm.directiveButtonClicked()" />
    </div>
```

Comment: just use `<button ng-click="onButtonClick()">Click Me</button>` instead so you can remove the whole link function

Answer (score 1):

Just remove ng-click and use this instead:

`element.click(function() {
    scope.onButtonClick();
 });`

Look at the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8PcsYj?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

In your directive, you are trying to access a function defined in the controller. But while defining your directive in view, you are not passing the correct reference to your function.
Try this: `<my-directive on-button-click="vm.directiveButtonClicked" />`
Instead of: `<my-directive on-button-click="vm.directiveButtonClicked()" />`

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?